# supabase database functions and RLS

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security

I am using supabase and i am trying to accomplish one thing.
I have a table called "customers", and it's like this:
customer_id, first_name, last_name,....., profile_id (from the profile table, where data of users is stored).
I have setup a simple RLS that let me do operations on this table that is as follow: (auth.id() = profile_id). In this way a user can see only its customers and its working fine.
Now i have a "contracts" table..
This table has a relationship with "customers" table, every customer can have multiple contracts.
I want to be able to select every contract from the contract table, only if the corresponding customer has a field that correspond to profile_id.
Is the same as the first RLS rule on the customer table, but i need it to use it on the contracts table and avoid inserting profile_id also on this table.
I'm new to postgres and supabase, can someone show me how it's done? Thanks

Comment: You can find an identical scenario being explained on this official RLS video from Supabase. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ow_Uzedfohk

Comment: Ok thanks, this worked.
```(EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM customers WHERE ((customers.customer_id = contracts.customer_id) AND (customers.point_id = auth.uid()))))```

Answer (score 0):

```
(EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM customers WHERE ((customers.customer_id = contracts.customer_id) AND (customers.point_id = auth.uid()))))
```